# Class constructor not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function ChartWrapper and a class called LineChart.

All the code: 
index.js ->

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js ->

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState, Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

import ChartWrapper from './ChartWrapper'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <ChartWrapper />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

ChartWrapper.js ->

```
import React, {Component, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import LineChart from './LineChart'

function ChartWrapper()  {
    const svgRef = useRef();
    console.log("works");

    useEffect( () => {
        const chart = <LineChart parent = {svgRef} />
        console.log(chart);
    }, []);


    return (
        <svg ref={svgRef}>

        </svg>
    );
}

export default ChartWrapper;
```

LineChart.js ->

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {scaleLinear} from 'd3-scale'
import {max} from 'd3-array'
import {select} from 'd3-selection'

class LineChart extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.svg = select(props.parent);
        console.log("does this work");
        console.log(this.svg);
    }    
}

export default LineChart;
```

The ChartWrapper function creates a LineChart object and passes a const as a prop. To check if the code is working, I have print statements. For some reason, the print statements in ChartWrapper work fine. The print statements in LineChart constructor class however do not.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

What you get in return when you log chart to the console is just an object representing the component, like this:

[image]

If you look at the type, it specifies the function/class to call. The class is only instantiated when it's rendered.

And the chart component is not returned, therefore react does not render it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the render method for LineChart